# mysql_fetch_array only showing 1 row when there's more

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a app that requires a DB and I'm getting some problems, the code seems good but its only printing 1 row when I have 2, I have tested when I have it with 5 and I still get 1.

What I'm wanting to do is make an array of all the item_id's; I know I'm getting all fields at the moment but that was just for testing.

**index.php:**

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost', 'aaran', '*********');
mysql_select_db('aaran_aff_io');

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `owner`='aaranmcguire'");
$results = mysql_fetch_array($query);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($results);

?>
```

**DB:**

[image: SQL DB]

**DB Structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(55) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `thumbnail` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `owner` varchar(55) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Amazing how many people can read an answer written here on SO, but can't read the manual

Comment: @MarkBaker i did, i was trying the print_r at first so it was skipping results, my bad i guess..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_array` only returns one row at a time. If you want all the rows placed into an array, you can iterate over the result set:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `owner`='aaranmcguire'");
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($rows);
```

Comment: thanks!... i was going something like this before but i was having problems because i was doing a separate print_r... [link](http://cl.ly/DDs7) i will accept it as a answer when it allows me.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the manual for [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://mysql_fetch_array).  It returns the next row when it's called.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_array()` only returns one row at a time so you must use a while loop to iterate over all the rows.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($row);
}
```